# How to bypass Disallowed Key Characters in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this problem in finding a solutions in Disallowed Key Characters in CodeIgniter. My problem is, I want that the `£` sign will be passed in through my url.

For example,

- I have this product `testing-product-nutella`.
- I want to add a `£` sign besides `testing-product-nutella£` somewhat like that. 
  here is my code below

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
            //--------------------------> Build the product list data--------------------------//
            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

```
        $prod_list              = Array();

        foreach($prods_query as $prod)
        {
            //echo htmlentities($prod['prod_name']);
            //print_r($prod);

            //$prod_name_url        = Make_into_url($prod['prod_name']);
            $prod_name_url      = htmlentities($prod['prod_name']);
            print_r($prod_name_url);

            // get the minimum order quantity and price from db
            if ($min_price = $this->Price_model->Get_listing_price($prod['prod_id']))
            {
                $min_order_qty      = $min_price['qty_value'];
                $min_order_price    = $min_price['price_amount'] > 0 ? number_format($min_price['price_amount'], 2) : false;
            }
            else
            {
                // this shouldn't happen but just in case...
                $min_order_qty      = "";
                $min_order_price    = "";
            }

            // get the default image for the product from the database
            $default_pic_row        = $this->Picture_model->Get_default_product_picture($prod['prod_id']);

            // get a list of all the special categories that a product is in
            $product_spec_cats      = $this->Special_category_model->Get_product_special_cats($prod['prod_id']);

            // is the product on special offer, if so, get the details
            $product_spec_off       = $this->Special_offer_model->Get_product_special_offer_details($prod['prod_id']);



            $nameUrl = urlencode($prod_name_url);
            echo "<pre>";
            echo $nameUrl;
            echo "</pre>";

            $prod_list[]            = Array(
                                            "prod_id"           => $prod['prod_id']
                                            ,"prod_name"        => urldecode($nameUrl)
                                            ,"prod_min_price"   => $min_order_price
                                            ,"prod_min_qty"     => $min_order_qty
                                            ,"prod_desc"        => $prod['prod_desc']
                                            ,"prod_code"        => $prod['prod_code']
                                            ,"prod_pic_thumb"   => $default_pic_row['pic_thumb']
                                            ,"product_colours_image"    => ""
                                            ,"prod_spec_cats"   => $product_spec_cats
                                            ,"prod_spec_off"    => $product_spec_off
                                            );
        }
```

When I tried to add a `£` sign it says Disallowed Key Characters. I want that when I add a special characters and passed in the url the product will display by having the special characters.

I tried to see the files in `system/libraries/Input.php` file and tried to change a lil bit on the code in `function _clean_input_keys` but it didnt work. Can someone help me figured this thing out? Any help is muchly appreciated.

TIA

Comment: what is the CodeIgniter version of yours ?

Comment: hmm i dont know.. maybe 2+ im just working some fixes issues

Comment: Show what `print_r($prod_name_url)` and `echo $nameUrl` output and comment which line is throwing the error with the actual error message

Comment: this is the print_r($prod_name_url) 
50ml Standard Clip Hand Sanitisers£50ml Standard Clip Hand Sanitisers£
and the 
$nameUrl = urlencode($prod_name_url);
     echo "<pre>";
     echo $nameUrl;
     echo "</pre>";
displays this one
50ml+Standard+Clip+Hand+Sanitisers%26pound%3B

Comment: hello can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to url encode the pound sign. Build your url string and then pass it to the php `urlencode($url)` function which will convert it into allowed characters: "%a3" for a "£"

To retrieve it use `urldecode($url)`

Comment: ahh i see so in this urldecode($url) the pound sign will read? and the page will able to display?

Comment: so ummm do i have not to touch the files in system/libraries/Input.php file?

Comment: Nope you just need to use `urlencode("testing-product-nutella£")` and it will create an url safe string for you. You cant put an unencoded £ in an url it needs to be converted to "%a3" which is the urlencoded version of this character

Comment: ahh ok so i will have to urlencode first then after saved in the databse when retrieved use the urldecode? is that it?

Comment: Yup sounds like it. When you want to make the url human readable use urldecode()

Comment: No it has nothing to do with the urlencode and then decode.. I think in the 
function _clean_input_keys it has to be changed

Comment: hello can you help me on this?

Comment: this is the url
50ml-Standard-Clip-Hand-Sanitisers£
and the error is this one
Disallowed Key Characters. products/details/50ml-Standard-Clip-Hand-SanitisersÂ£

Comment: You will need to update your question and show what you are doing with the url

Comment: umm what i want is that i want that the pound sign when passed into the url the page will display it says disallowed key character

Comment: i want to bypass the disallowed key character

Comment: As above you need to update your question and show your actual code. Nobody can help you otherwise

Comment: i added this line of code
urlencode($prod_name_url);
above

Comment: hello can you pls help me on this?